# coldfusion 8 monitoring alert edit email subject line

Tags: coldfusion, monitoring, administration, coldfusion-8

in coldfusion 8 enterprise, is it possible to set the subject line of alert messages sent out from the coldfusion enterprise monitoring tool?  I have done considerable research, however, I have not been able to find anything to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can run your own CFC to respond to an Alert, couldn't that CFC send an email with whatever subject you wish?

Comment: Yep, that's a good workaround, it seems. Thanks for suggesting it, Ray. Still, Chris, I do think it would be helpful to be able to modify it more directly (even if per a property or XML file, if not in the settings page of the monitor).

Comment: thank you both for your comments, I will have to post a request for a future enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen or heard of such an ability. Sorry, I know that's not an "answer". But since I may be one of the most avid users and [writers about the monitor](http://www.carehart.org/articles/#2007_2), I thought it may be of at least some value to hear that I've not heard of such an ability.

It's an interesting idea, though, yes, and you ought to [file a feature request](http://cfbugs.adobe.com) for it, Chris. Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way of doing this.  But I have spent a couple of hours experimenting, so I'll share that to save somebody else the trouble:

My problem : I want to add server information into the subject line of the alert email so we know which server is reporting the problem, using ColdFusion 10 (but I've tried this in CF8 in the past).

I searched the CF installation for all occurrences of "Slow Server"

```
sudo grep -ar 'Slow Server' /opt/coldfusion10/
```

There are only two files, I was a bit optimistic because they are both language files - multiserver_resource_en.xml and smresource_en.xml.  But no luck. Those files change the interface text, but not the email text (so the text "Slow Server Alert" in the alerts table is translated from the data name "SLOWSERVERALERT" in smresource_en.xml).

I searched for other likely strings in other likely files and folders, but found nothing.  I guess the email text is compiled into a jar file.